# Framework Front-End Developer

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, frameworks

So I am a Front-End Developer. So far, I designed the website manually, and it has been fun and easy with me.

But today I got a job interview for the position of Front-End Developer (I hope I will be hired soon). In the interview, the interviewers (Back-End Developers) seems glad to see my portfolios. However, when they asked me about what kind of framework I used to use, I don't have any idea to answer it. So far, I just use bracket as my webs editor. And then they pointed out that they like bootstrap.

My question is, is it important for the front-end developer to use framework? what if I don't use any framework? I just read that framework or bootstrap makes us easier to construct our websites, but I just found it not natural and not easy to comprehend.

Answer (score 4):

> what if I don't use any framework?

(I'm assuming you mean a CSS framework specifically. Frontend JS frameworks are a whole other can of worms.)
It seems that companies often end up *de facto* creating their own CSS frameworks, although they don't always do so intentionally and don't always consciously think of their creation as a framework. So you may arguably end up using one anyway.
But your question seems to be more specifically about third-party general-purpose CSS frameworks, like Bootstrap or Foundation. By not using them, you lose out on:

- availability of integrated third-party extensions/plugins/widgets
- the extensive real-world battle-testing these frameworks have been put through and the corresponding fixes they've received
- saving work by not having to create many common widgets from scratch (including documentation)
- the ability to hire people who are already familiar with the framework you're using
- having knowledge of the framework be a fully transferable (and thus more valuable) skill

On the other hand, you gain:

- complete unbridled ability to customize things to suit your exact needs and personal tastes (Bootstrap & Foundation do offer a decent degree of customization, but there are limits and there are some basic design choices that cannot reasonably be changed)
- virtually no superfluous CSS, assuming you maintain things properly (although again, Bootstrap & Foundation both offer some level of ability to omit unwanted components)
- (I am sure there are some additional positives, but I am biased and tired and can't come up with more at the moment.)

Answer (score 1):

So if you want your product/solution to be set according to  industrial standards. My advice is yes - If we stick to the [definition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_framework) ...  *universal, reusable software platform to develop software applications, products and solutions.*

Also you can take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25247685/gui-architecture-design-resources) and my answer with helpful resources.

- Cheers